# RegExp: поиск тега с определённым значением атрибута

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть вот такой код:

```html
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-unit_border_active_color"><?= $entry_border_active_color ?></label><div class="col-sm-10"><input data-mark="<?= $mark ?>" size="60" type="text" name="unit_border_active_color" value="<?= $border_active_color ?>"></div>
```

Не получается написать регулярное выражение, которое сможет извлечь весь тег по слову `unit_border_active_color`.

Регулярка `<(|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>` возвращает *любые* валидные теги, а мне нужен только один - в котором есть последовательность `unit_border_active_color`. Я не знаю, как добавить исключение в эту регулярку, чтобы результат был такой:

```html
<input size="60" type="text" name="unit_border_active_color" value="<?= $border_active_color ?>">
```

Comment: А какой результат должен быть? Кст, не рекомендуется парсить xml/html регулярками: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5909792

Comment: вот такой результат ```<input size="60" type="text" name="unit_border_active_color" value="<?= $border_active_color ?>">```

Comment: Вот тут https://regex101.com/r/b7YObu/1 - можно например попробовать настроить игнорирование данных в кавычках, как в примере сделал

Comment: а можно вот в этот код ```<(|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>```,который возвращает все валидные теги, как-нибудь вставить unit_border_active_color, чтобы возвращался только один нужный мне тег с этим словом внутри?

Answer (score 1):

Для вашего случая, в PHP регулярное выражение и код будут такими:

```php
$re = '/.*?(<input[\s\S]*\bunit_border_active_color\b[\s\S]*>)(?=<).*/mi';

$str = '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-unit_border_active_color"><?= $entry_border_active_color ?></label><div class="col-sm-10"><input data-mark="<?= $mark ?>" size="60" type="text" name="unit_border_active_color" value="<?= $border_active_color ?>"></div>';

echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace($re, '$1', $str), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Рабочий пример на JS:

```js
let rExp = /.*?(<input[\s\S]*\bunit_border_active_color\b[\s\S]*>)(?=<).*/gim;
let sHtml = `<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-unit_border_active_color"><?= $entry_border_active_color ?></label><div class="col-sm-10"><input data-mark="<?= $mark ?>" size="60" type="text" name="unit_border_active_color" value="<?= $border_active_color ?>"></div>`;
console.log(sHtml.replace(rExp, '$1'));
```